# Question about compactness of a set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Fix a $\delta > 0$. Is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: d(x, K) \leq \delta\}$ also compact? Here $d(x, K) = \inf_{y \in K}|x - y|$.

Comment: Can you prove or disprove it is closed and bounded?

Comment: Hint: Heine-Borel tells you compact <=> closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. You should easily be able to show the diameter of the set is less than the diameter of $K$ + $2 \delta$. Now, is it closed?

Comment: The set is closed because it is the inverse image of a closed set.